# Can I set my WP_Query to be a Main Query?

Tags: wp-query, loop, pre-get-posts

When I create a `WP_Query` it's automatically considered a "secondary query", but what if I replace my main query with a WP_Query? Can I set my WP_Query to be considered a "Main Query"?

The reason I say this is because I need to use `pre_get_posts` to do some filtering. My current logic looks like this:

```
if(isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'my_post_type')
```

The problem with the above logic is that I have 2 queries in the same template of the same post type but only one of them is my core query, the query I want to label as "Main Query" so I can use a conditional such as `$query->is_main_query()` to differentiate the two and filter accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an overly complicated approach. `pre_get_posts` will work for any query and there are numerous ways to control when/how the callback behaves:

1. Add and remove the callback:

   ```
   function dummy_action($q) {

   }

   add_action('pre_get_posts','dummy_action');
   $q = new WP_Query(
     array(
       'post_type' => 'post'
     )
   );
   remove_action('pre_get_posts','dummy_action');
   ```
2. Use a self-removing callback:

   ```
   function dummy_action($q) {
     remove_action('pre_get_posts','dummy_action');
   }

   add_action('pre_get_posts','dummy_action');
   $q = new WP_Query(
     array(
       'post_type' => 'post'
     )
   );
   ```
3. Feed the query a parameter you can use as a trigger:

   ```
   function dummy_action($q) {
     if ($q->get('action_trigger')) {
       // do something
     }
   }

   add_action('pre_get_posts','dummy_action');
   $q = new WP_Query(
     array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'action_trigger' => true
     )
   );
   ```

You do not want to "assign" a secondary query as the main query. That will cause the same issues as caused by using `query_posts()`, which essentially does assign a secondary query as the main query.

Comment: See I usually run with Option 3 (similar) but was hoping there was a better way to go about it. This may be better as another question, but what exactly are the problems when you overwrite the main query? I know `query_posts()` is a run around to `WP_Query` but what inherit issues come with overwriting the main query with your own?

Comment: WordPress depends on a number of `globals`, one of which is `$wp_query`. Anything that depends on that `global` will be effected if you clobber it. How much effect it has depends on the theme and the installed plugins, and on where in the page load you clobber the query. Just don't do it.